# Difference between IAM authorizer and API key in AWS API Gateway in terms of security

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am seeing an online course in which the instructor explains that in order to make your internal AWS Api Gateways secure (internal means that users don't need to call these endpoints, and they will be called by the code itself) you have two choices, setting a key for the REST API or setting an IAM authorizer for it. Then he explains that the second one is more secure since we send a request that is signed with our credentials (AWS secret access key) to the API gateway to authorize the call. His justification for doing this is that if we set a key instead of doing this, someone who has access to the code may steel our API access key. But I think that if you want to sign your API call you should put your AWS credentials in the code, so if someone can have access to our code, they can steel your AWS credentials and then making a signed request with it shouldn't be that hard.

All that said, I think there is something about this that I don't know, could you please explain to me if one of these methods is more secure than the other one and why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I think that if you want to sign your API call you should put your AWS credentials in the code,

No, this is **a bad practice** and a security risk, for the exact reason you are mentioning. If you run your code, which calls your REST API, on EC2 instance, ECS container or Lambda function, you should use **IAM roles**.

For example, if your code runs on an EC2 instance you would use [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) which provides **temporary** credentials to your app. Also these are not your credentials, but they belong to the role which would only allow for calling the said API, nothing else. This is based on the [least privileged principle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege).